# How to show multiple post types on taxonomy archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

On a taxonomy archive, how does one create multiple loops for different post types that share that taxonomy? I'm using taxonomy-themes.php so that it applies to all three of the terms in the 'themes' taxonomy (climate change, governance, peace building).

On each term's archive page, I want to output the main taxonomy loop (posts), and then I want to create loops for each of 'events', 'resources' and 'staff' (all of which are custom post types). I'm assuming that I create new wp_query for each of the post types, but how do I tell that query which term I want it to get 'events' from (ie. the current archives' term)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, if you want separate loops for different post types you'll need to use a separate `WP_Query()` for post type. In the template you can get the current term (ID) being viewed via: `get_queried_object_id()` (see [source](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/))

```
$args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'staff',
          'tax_query' => array( 
             array(
              'taxonomy' => 'themes',      
              'terms' => get_queried_object_id(),
              'field' => 'id'
             )
          ),
        );
$staff = WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks very much Stephen. That did it perfectly. And wow is queryposts.com helpful.